# Does the openssh server automatically accept a new host key?

Tags: kubernetes, openssh

I have an openssh server (OPENSSH_VERSION=8.8_p1-r1) running in a container that gets its host key per volume. Kubernetes takes care of updating the volume.

Does the openssh server also have to be restarted, reloaded or does it accept a changed host key automatically - similar to updating the authorized_keys?

Comment: This might get a better answer on the Unix site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the release note OpenSSH has supported (RFC8332 RSA/SHA-256/512) signatures since release 7.2 and existing ssh-rsa keys will automatically use the stronger algorithm where possible.It means there is no need to accept any keys but if you need to  add auto accept the new key use the following command

<StrictHostKeyChecking=accept-new>

expand the StrictHostKeyChecking option with two new settings. The first "accept-new" will automatically accept hitherto-unseen keys but will refuse connections for changed or invalid hostkeys.

For more info follow [open ssh release 8.8](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-8.8) .